# How to query rows from 2 tables in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

```
TABLE 1
student_id | name
-----------------
1          | A
2          | B
3          | C
4          | D

TABLE 2
vote_id   | student_id | vote_for
------------------------------
1          | 1          | 2
2          | 1          | 3
3          | 2          | 1
4          | 1          | 4
```

How can I get records from `TABLE 1` (student names B C D) based on `student_id` in `TABLE 2` (student_id 1) in a single query? I managed to do it but in multiple queries like below:

```
$students = array();
$query = "SELECT vote_for FROM table2 WHERE student_id=?";          
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$student_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($vote_for);
$votes = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $votes[] = $vote_for;
}
$stmt->close();
if (!empty($votes)) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE student_id=?";
    foreach ($votes as $vote) {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$vote);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array(); 
            $temp['name'] = $name; 
            $students[] = $temp;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` query to get the names of the students that were voted for by a given student_id. For example:

```
SELECT s.name AS voted_for
FROM table2 v
JOIN table1 s ON s.student_id = v.vote_for
WHERE v.student_id = 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3004892142678eeebcf44dc76676ef73)

In PHP:

```
$students = array();
$query = "SELECT s.name AS voted_for
    FROM table2 v
    JOIN table1 s ON s.student_id = v.vote_for
    WHERE v.student_id = ?";          
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$student_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $students[] = array('name' => $name);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Superb! I remove the `AS voted_for` though, because I don't see the use of it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve it with the following query:

```
SELECT T1.STUDENT_ID, T1.NAME 
FROM TABLE_1 T1, TABLE_2 T2
WHERE T1.STUDENT_ID = T2.VOTE_FOR
AND T2.STUDENT_ID = ?
```

And you would just inject the `STUDENT_ID` for the Table 2. You can remove the T1.STUDENT_ID if necessary.